# File types search pattern in VS find

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In the visual studio 2015 find and replace window you can specify file types to look in for:
[image: find_and_Replace_vs2015]

*Looking in `*.cs`-Files*

There, you can enter sth like `*.cs` which searches in i.e. Program.cs and Class1.cs.
`*.as?x` searches in Program.as**P**x and Program.as**C**x.
I've found no other way to enter a pattern except the wildcard characters `*`(any item 0 to infinit times) and `?`(any item one time).

Is it possible to use any other pattern here to search in cs and resx-files, i.e. `*.(resx|cs)`[this doesnt work]? Is it possible to use some kind of regex like in the *Find what*-field?

In *Find what* you may use the regex [defined here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx).

Comment: I really don't see your question. What is your question? You point to the regex resource link--does that not answer your question??? What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: @Jazimov *Is it possible to use any other pattern here to search in cs and resx-files, i.e. *.(resx|cs)[this doesnt work]? Is it possible to use some kind of regex like in the Find what-field?* I'm looking for a way to look in more than one file type like .cs and .resx

Comment: In that case, RichieHindle answered. But you said you were looking for a "pattern", so I didn't know if you wanted an answer that specifically leverages RegEx. If you don't, then your answer has been posted.

Comment: @Jazimov I hoped for the best and regex would've been ideal. But his answer already helps me a lot. Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter a semicolon-separated list of patterns, like this: `*.resx;*.cs`

Comment: Is it also possible to exclude files? we got many generated files like *.g.cs.

Comment: No, I don't think you can.  You might want to check out Entrian Source Search http://entrian.com/source-search/ which does all this and more [full disclosure: Entrian Source Search is a commercial product and I'm its author].